# Disable a system-wide (pip) package inside a virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I have a package installed through pip system-wide that I do not want to use inside a virtualenv. Inside that virtualenv I want to test a development built of that package. Is there anyway to disable the system-wide(global?) package so that it won't conflict with the test built I am about to install inside the virtualenv? Or if I keep the system-wide one installed, would it cause any conflicts?

Comment: This should be the default behaviour unless the virtual environment is created with the [`--system-site-packages`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) option.